# MS Access Date Grouping is not working in report

Tags: ms-access, report

I have created a simple Microsoft Access 2007 app of receiving and paying vouchers, everything is working properly but one thing that my mind doesn't solve.

I have created a report template of "Receiving Amount" where I want report be grouped in respect of receiving date. I have added a field named "Receiving Date" in "Group, Sort and Total" and when I generate it, it doesn't group the content in respect of date.

Comment: If the field with date contains also time, you won't be able to group by days using directly this field, use Format function for field with grouping

Comment: It is _Medium Date_ format which doesn't contains time.

Comment: The format is for display only. The report groups on the true value of "Receiving Date".

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your *Grouping and Sorting* to use the expression:

```
Fix([Receiving Date])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The reason of not grouping date wise because Access could not understand the date, like **Gustav** said, format is just for display but actual value is different and **Sergey S** said "If the field with date contains time. you won't be able to group the report".

Finally, I had to remove time from the date and keep it clear to Access so it can group my report.

```
=MonthName(DatePart("m",[receiving date])) & " " & Format$([receiving date],"d"", ""yyyy")
```

> Where **receiving date** is the field name.

Comment: That can be reduced to: `=Format([receiving date], "mmmm d, yyyy")`